# input of layer is incompatible with the layer expected input is

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, generative-adversarial-network

I have tried making a GAN training network, I have tried using a few existing networks and I have reached the same error on each one

```
 ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential_17 is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 2 but received input with shape (None, 256, 256, 1)
```

I have read this is caused by not batching my data but I clearly do batch it in the fit function:

```
d_loss_real = discriminator.fit(x=ab, y=y_train_real,batch_size=20,epochs=2,verbose=1)
```

The model that crashed is:

```
def discriminator():
        model = Sequential()
        model.add(Conv2D(32,(3,3), padding='same',strides=2,input_shape=d_image_shape))
        model.add(LeakyReLU(0.2))
        model.add(Dropout(0.25))
        
        model.add(Conv2D(64,(3,3),padding='same',strides=2))
        model.add(BatchNormalization())
        model.add(LeakyReLU(.2))
        model.add(Dropout(0.25))
        
        
        model.add(Conv2D(128,(3,3), padding='same', strides=2))
        model.add(BatchNormalization())
        model.add(LeakyReLU(0.2))
        model.add(Dropout(0.25))
        
        
        model.add(Conv2D(256,(3,3), padding='same',strides=2))
        model.add(BatchNormalization())
        model.add(LeakyReLU(0.2))
        model.add(Dropout(0.25))
        
        
        model.add(Flatten())
        model.add(Dense(1))
        model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))
        
        image = Input(shape=d_image_shape)
        validity = model(image)
        return Model(image,validity)

        image = Input(shape=d_image_shape)
        validity = model(image)
        return Model(image,validity)
```

The ab and L values are:

```
L = np.array([rgb_to_lab(image,l=True) for image in X_train])
AB = np.array([rgb_to_lab(image,ab=True) for image in X_train])
```

The rgb_to_lab function:

```
def rgb_to_lab(img, l=False, ab=False):

    img = img / 255
    l = color.rgb2lab(img)[:,:,0]
    l = l / 50 - 1
    l = l[...,np.newaxis]

    ab = color.rgb2lab(img)[:,:,1:]
    ab = (ab + 128) / 255 * 2 - 1
    if l.all():
        return l
    else: return ab

def lab_to_rgb(img):

    new_img = np.zeros((256,256,3))
    for i in range(len(img)):
        for j in range(len(img[i])):
            pix = img[i,j]
            new_img[i,j] = [(pix[0] + 1) * 50,(pix[1] +1) / 2 * 255 - 128,(pix[2] +1) / 2 * 255 - 128]
    new_img = color.lab2rgb(new_img) * 255
    new_img = new_img.astype('uint8')
    return new_img
```

Comment: What is `d_image_shape`?

Comment: The variable d_image_shape=(256,256,2)

Comment: And what is `ab`?

Comment: I edited the post for the ab and L values and the function they use

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do with your function `rgb_to_lab`, but this function will return almost in every case `l` which has only one channel. You might want to fix that thing.

Answer (score 0):

You need to reshape data before feeding it to Conv2D layer.The image has 3 channels, but the first layer has 32 channels. The first layer should have same channel as input image.
Add keras input

```
keras.Input(shape=(256, 256, 3))
```